# save flash as3 codes into a jpeg file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jpeg

How do I save all my codes into a JPEG? It will be inputted into my report, I was going to single-handed print screen and just edit but that would take forever.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be an off-topic, doesn't it?

Comment: You would have to write a program to parse your code files into a multiline text field until its full. Then it would capture that text field and export the capture as a .jpeg then repeat the steps. Why do you want to represent code as an image, just wondering?

Comment: Agree with @JonnyHenly here I am curious why you would want to do this.  You can use SnagIt (a commercial screen capture program, believe they have "shareware" version as well), it lets you click a scrollable region and capture the whole thing into an image (stitches it all together).  Jonny's suggestion would work too if you wanted to write an AIR app to do it (probably about 2hrs of work, rough guess).

Answer (score 1):

In your code editor you can go to each class file and click `File > print`. Then print to a file (maybe pdf). You would need to do this for each class file. If you need them in JPG, then you can open a pdf in photoshop, then save as JPG.